# Remove overlapping area

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

Blender version: 2.79 ( I can not change this at the moment! )

I am trying to remove the area from a mesh that is overlapping with the area from another.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_interior_faces()
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type="FACE")
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")
```

I also tried to use the boolean modifiers (union) on the original two meshes to no avail.

Comment: I talked to an expert with 7+ years of experience in Blender and he says it is not possible.

Comment: It might be that the Python library Shapely has some ways to do this.